# Anchor color on hover state not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-selectors

I would like ALL my anchors text to turn to green while being hovered on.
I expected `a:hover{ color: green; }` to work but it doesn't.
Could someone explain me why ?
Thank you.

Here is my code:

```css
a:hover{
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<link rel='stylesheet' href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="container-fluid">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-default" role="navigation">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                  <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
            </div>

            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
                </form>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </nav>
</div>
<!-- end container -->
```

Also on [Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/aqjpGg)

Answer (score 4):

Bootstrap uses classes to style their nav links. When using styles, there's a weight to the prioritization of styles. `a:hover` by itself will get overridden by `.nav.navbar-nav li a:hover`, even if it was defined before your code.

Read about this here:
https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/

P.S.
Try your best not to tack on `!important` to your styles. It makes changing things down the line much more difficult, makes your code maintainability incredibly difficult and will make anyone working on your project like you not as much as they should :)

There are definitely times where `!important` is needed, but I'd just like to say be conservative in its use.

Answer (score 1):

You are using Bootstrap which has defined the colours on anchors is various places.

Rather than just overriding Bootstrap (and there are multiple cases where this will be needed to cover all anchors) make use of Bootstraps inbuilt combustibility.

Download the source, update the applicable SASS variables that control the colours and include the source in your build process.

With Bootstrap pre-4 there are a couple of other options: tools to download a ready customised Bootstrap (essentially do the work of modifying the SASS variables and transpiling for you). Or use a Bootstrap theme. (Overriding `$navbar-default-brand-hover-color` will change the hover colour in the navbar.)

Any of these will initially take longer, but when the next "just change that" requirement comes along you'll be in a position to do it quickly.

Comment: I think this is a really good answer for non-beginners. If I had seen this answer a year ago, I wouldn't have understood it. Seeing it now, I think it's a wonderful solution, especially for my Rails projects. I guess what I'm saying is, if you're a beginner and are dismissing this answer, bookmark this page and look at it a few months from now, you may have a new insight.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using bootstrap library navbar it has its own define css classes therefore you are not able to see the changes.

Please use

```
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a:hover, .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a:focus{
  color: green;
}
```

-Help :)

Comment: good suggestion but I want all a tags to be green not just one of them

Answer (score 0):

```
add this

.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a:hover{
 color: green;
 }
```

Comment: good suggestion but I want all a tags to be green not just one of them

Answer (score 0):

The "navbar" class is already applying a style to  tags inside it. It overrides your custom style.

CSS is interpreted. A style declared first, will be overridden by the same style declared after it. So just change up the order in which you're including your style sheets. Plugins and frameworks first. Custom styles come last.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://bootstrap.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet"href="mystyles.css" />
```

Now the styles in mystyles.css will override anything that the plugin has of the same name instead of the other way around.

New styles, should have the same specificity as the ones they're overriding (unless they have !important). Refer (Specificity)[https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity].

For this case

```
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover {
    color : green;
}
```

as opposed to

```
a {
    color : green;
}
```

Comment: This won't work where Bootstrap's selectors have higher specificity.

Comment: Ah yes, should add that in

Answer (score 0):

Whatever the framework in use, to determine what could be the css rule that fits, inspect the element with the developer console first.  In this case you will find this:
`.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a:hover {…`

The thing is, your new rule have to be even [more specific](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) to take over the original one. The more specific, the more specifi your rule is the more it will *rule them all*.

According to [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) documentation, here is a list of selector types increases by specificity.

> 0 — Type selectors (e.g., h1) and pseudo-elements (e.g., ::before).
>   1 — Class selectors (e.g., .example), attributes selectors (e.g., [type="radio"]) and pseudo-classes (e.g., :hover).
>   2 — ID selectors (e.g., #example).

You want all anchors (of your page?) to be illegible, then for the rule not to be too verbose, you might need to add an `id` attribute on some top most ancestor that is common to all anchors! You must such a top container block (could also be html or body tags but that would feel ugly)…

Here is what you get when adding a `<div id="common-ancestor">` surrounding all your code:

```css
#common-container a:hover{
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel='stylesheet' href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="common-container">
  <div class="container-fluid">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-default" role="navigation">
          <div class="container-fluid">
              <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
              <div class="navbar-header">
                  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                  </button>
                  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
              </div>

              <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
              <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                      <li class="active"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                      <li class="dropdown">
                          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
                          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                              <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                              <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                              <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                              <li class="divider"></li>
                              <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                              <li class="divider"></li>
                              <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                          </ul>
                      </li>
                  </ul>
                  <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
                      <div class="form-group">
                          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
                      </div>
                      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
                  </form>
                  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                      <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                      <li class="dropdown">
                          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
                          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                              <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                              <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                              <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                              <li class="divider"></li>
                              <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                          </ul>
                      </li>
                  </ul>
              </div>
              <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
          </div>
          <!-- /.container-fluid -->
      </nav>
  </div>
  <!-- end container -->

</div>
<!-- end "#common-container"-->
```

The **Joker**:
You may have heard of the `!important` suffix eg `color: green !important;`.
Usually it is used as a last resort like if you are absolutely sure you will not need to override the rule it is applied to (but who does!?) and existing rules are to complicated to be overridden).
The only way to override rules having `!important` is to write another rule with `!important` that will appear later in your source code (interpreted later by the css engine).
Improper use or over-using it will surely lead you to complete madness, use at your own risks.

Answer (score -2):

add this  `!important`

```
a:hover{
  color: green !important;
}
```

By default, it was white. In order to override it, you need to put `!important`

**NOTE**
Only use `!important` to override if you feel need it. Otherwise, you need to change the `a` to specific class name

Comment: Once you start using `!important` you'll keep using it as a quick fix, and then you'll be stuck because there is no `!really-important` to override it.

Comment: Then what is the best way to do it? @Richard

Comment: As other answers have noted: make the selector sufficiently specific to have priority.

Comment: @Richard OK.. To make it clear since you act like somewhat SO SO.. Question is about how to make the a tag changing color on hover.. I think my answer is the best fit for the global element tag

Comment: @Stavm "Write all code assuming the next maintainer is a psychopath who knows where you live".

Comment: @Richard I removed my comment in honor of yours. your comment deserves more +1s.

Comment: @halmos you need to use this.. since you want all `a` tags instead of specific `a` tag